# SQL Server 2008 R2: sum of rows without partition

Tags: sql-server, sum, rows

My query result is like

[image]

i want something like  this (multiple sum based on srblckd column for each custid)

[image]

I have googled and tried multiple combinations. I could create query like this (with order 1,4). I think partition is not possible in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
select 
    max(cst.custID) as custID,
    max(custname) as custname,
    max(roomtype) as roomtype,
    sum(srblckd) as SRBlckd  
from 
    SlpRooms 
join 
    EVENT on SRHdrID = EVENT.EvtID 
join 
    CUSTT cst on EVENT.CustID = cst.CustID 
join 
    SALPT slps on EVENT.SPID = slps.salesid 
join 
    roomtypes on roomtypes.roomtypeid = SlpRooms.srtypeid 
where 
    convert(varchar(10), SRDate, 120) between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-29'   
group by 
    SRDate, cst.custID, srtypeid  

union all

select max(cst.custID) as custID,max(custname) as custname,max(roomtype) as roomtype,sum(srblckd) as SRBlckd  from SlpRooms join EVENT on SRHdrID =EVENT.EvtID join CUSTT cst on EVENT.CustID=cst.CustID join SALPT slps on EVENT.SPID=slps.salesid join roomtypes on roomtypes.roomtypeid=SlpRooms.srtypeid where convert(varchar(10),SRDate, 120) between '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-29' group by SRDate ,cst.custID   order by 1,4
```

but this is not working. what more can i try?

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Also don't order by ordinal position. If you change your query the ordering will be all wrong. For the question at hand....I don't understand what you are trying to do at all. Are you trying to inject a total row after each customer? That sounds like a job for the front end, not the sql server.

Comment: See [Sql Server Rollup](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rollup/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you could do a Rollup. Personally I like the control of just writing **Grouping Sets**

Here's an example using data somewhat similar to yours:

```
DECLARE @Datum TABLE (Date DATE, custID INT, custname VARCHAR(100), roomtype VARCHAR(100), SRBlckd INT) 

INSERT INTO @Datum
(
    Date,
    custID,
    custname,
    roomtype,
    SRBlckd
)

VALUES('2-1-2020',239, 'Value1','Value1',1),
('2-1-2020',384, 'Value2','Value2',1),
('2-1-2020',384, 'Value3','Value3',75),
('2-1-2020',384, 'Value4','Value4',3),
('2-1-2020',408, 'Value5','Value5',17),
('2-1-2020',3182, 'Value6','Value6',25)

SELECT Date,
   custID,
   ISNULL(custname,'Total'),
   roomtype,
   SUM(SRBlckd )

FROM @datum
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
(Date, custId, CustName, roomType, SRBLCKD),
(CustID)
)
```

Comment: I always forget about GROUPING SETS. I don't do this type of query very often.